# How to add keys for AppIndexing in android? To make the app more reachable

Tags: android, android-app-indexing, google-app-indexing

I am developing an app and I need to specify the keywords which will make my app more reachable. It can be done using app indexing but I am not sure where the keywords should be added.
Any Help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

To get discovered on google play search follow these instructions:
https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/4448378?hl=en

App Indexing puts your app in front of users who use Google Search. It works by indexing the URL patterns you provide in your app manifest and using API calls from your app to make content within your app available to both existing and new users.
More info regarding App Indexing: https://developers.google.com/app-indexing/

Cheers,

MB